# cx_freeze doesn't create .exe file on a python script that uses subprocess to run other python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze a python program that is just a menu with choices to run other python scripts.  I am using subprocess to run each script choice in the main program (menu).  The program itself runs fine, but when I try to create the executable using cx_freeze, the creation process seems to be interrupted, and the resulting .exe file does not run any of the subprocesses.  I have tried to use other methods to call the chosen python scripts, such as os and call, but can't get them to work.  Please help me so that I can get a working .exe file.  This is part of the main script using subprocess:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button, Label
import subprocess
import sys
import os    

class menu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.mymaster = master   
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.menu_container()
        self.fill0_frame()
        self.title()
        self.bottom_frame()
        self.play_or_quit())

    def menu_container(self):
        self.menu_container = tk.Toplevel(self)

    ...
    ...
    ....
    def play_or_quit(self):
        self.play_or_quit = Frame(self.bottom_frame,width=100,background="grey")
        self.play_or_quit.grid(row=2,column=5)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.play_or_quit, command = import_cw2)
        self.button1_name = "childwindow2"
        self.button1.configure(text=self.button1_name,             background="violet",width=16)
        self.button1.grid(row=17,column=10,sticky = "ES")
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.play_or_quit, command = import_cwp4)
        self.button2_name = "childwindowprimes4"
        self.button2.configure(text=self.button2_name, background="pink",width=16)
        self.button2.grid(row=18,column=10,sticky = "ES")
        self.button3 = Button(self.play_or_quit, command = import_TSF) #height=1,width=2)
        self.button3_name = "The Seiji Factor"  
        self.button3.configure(text=self.button3_name, background="tan",width=16)
        self.button3.grid(row=19,column=10,sticky = "ES")   
        self.button4 = Button(self.play_or_quit, command = self.finished, height=1,width=2)
        self.button4_name = "Quit"  
        self.button4.configure(text=self.button4_name, background="red",width=16)
        self.button4.grid(row=20,column=10,sticky= "ES")
...
def import_cw2(): #,event
    theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "cw2gameframes.py"])
    theproc.communicate()       

def import_cwp4():
    theproc2 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "cwp4gameframes.py"])
    theproc2.communicate()

def import_TSF():
    theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "SeijiFactorgameframes.py"])
    theproc.communicate()         

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    application = menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```